# Table data does not reload dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an navigation based app in which table data entered dynamically though another page. But when navigate back to table , it does not show the data. It  shows the data only after existing application and relaunching it. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
listOfNotes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApplicationDatabase.sqlite"]];
const char *dbPath=[databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sql="select notes from message";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){

        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *list=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            [listOfNotes addObject:list];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
tableData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tableData addObjectsFromArray:listOfNotes];

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to reload the table by

```
[table reloadData];
```

Comment: nsmutablearray may not respond to [tabledata reloadData]

Comment: in [table reloadData]; the table, is reference of your table not to your array... dnt write [tableData reloadData] as tableData is an array.